# If the numerator has a higher degree than the denominator, is there no horizontal asymptote? And vice versa, is it 0?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example,

$$\frac{2x-4}{x^2-x-2}$$

Since the denominator has a higher degree than the numerator, will the horizontal asymptote always be zero?

And if we had this,

$$\frac{2x^3-4}{x^2-x-2}$$

Would there be no horizontal asymptote everytime, as long as the numerator has a higher degree than the denominator?

Comment: Yes and yes. (HA of the graph of $y=$ your expression, of couse.)

Comment: In the second case, there would be a slant asymptote instead of the horizontal one.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to confirm this since I have a test tomorrow :)